# creating a dynamic search query in php and pdo

Tags: php, pdo

Ive been trying to get this to work but I dont think my sql is setup correctly.

For instance I am trying to get a search word from the URL and then insert it using prepared statements so that its safe to use in the database.

First I call the userid of the products they own from the sessions.

Then I check if they have more than 1 item, if they do I setup an array and insert into database, if they do not have more than 1 item then I just simply insert into database to retrieve data.

The reason why I am setting it into variables is because its being sent to the pagination class so it will paginate the results.

Here is the header of the html:

```
<?php

$searchword = $urlmaker->geturlandsearch($_GET["search"]);

$findcomma = strpos($_SESSION["SESS_USERSPRODUCTIDS"], ",");

if($findcomma == true){

    $userproductid = explode(',', $_SESSION["SESS_USERSPRODUCTIDS"]);
    $prep       = array(':like' => "%$searchword%", ':like2' => "%$searchword%");

    $q = '';
    $e = '';
    $i = 1;

    foreach($userproductid as $productid){

        $q   .= 'productid=:productid' . $i . ' || ';
        $prep[":productid{$i}"] = $productid;
        $i++;

    }

    $q = rtrim($q, " || ");

} else {

    $q = 'productid=:productid';
    $prep = array(':productid' => $_SESSION["SESS_USERSPRODUCTIDS"], ':like' => "%$searchword%", ':like2' => "%$searchword%");

}

$maxlimit = 15;

$geturi = "/Search-Forum/" . $_GET['search'] . "/";

$string     = "SELECT id,title,date,username,viewcount,replycount,replyuser,replydate FROM forum_topics WHERE " . $q . " AND title LIKE :like OR content like :like2 ORDER BY replydate DESC";
$pagstring  = "SELECT id FROM forum_topics WHERE  " . $q . " AND title LIKE :like OR content like :like2";
$pagurl     = $geturi;
```

Here is the frontend code:

```
<?php

$topicQuery = $pagination->paginatedQuery($pdo, $string, $maxlimit, $prep);
if($topicQuery != "no query"){

while($fetchquery = $topicQuery->fetch()) { 
$topicid            = stripslashes($fetchquery["id"]);
$topictitle         = stripslashes($fetchquery["title"]);
$topicdate          = stripslashes($fetchquery["date"]);
$topicusername      = stripslashes($fetchquery["username"]);
$topicviewcount     = stripslashes($fetchquery["viewcount"]);
$topicreplycount    = stripslashes($fetchquery["replycount"]);
$topicreplyuser     = stripslashes($fetchquery["replyuser"]);
$topicreplydate     = stripslashes($fetchquery["replydate"]);

?>
<li>
    <div class="topiclisttitle"><p><b><a href="<?php echo '/Forum-'.$_GET["forumid"].'/Product-'.$_GET["productid"].'/' . $urlmaker->sluggify($topictitle); ?>/<?php echo $topicid ; ?>/<?php echo $_GET["proid"]; ?>/"><?php echo ucwords($topictitle); ?></a></b><br><?php echo $topicusername ; ?> on <?php echo $betterTime->dateAndtime($topicdate); ?></p></div>
    <div class="topiclistview"><p><b><?php echo $topicviewcount ; ?></b><br>Views</p></div>
    <div class="topiclistview"><p><b><?php echo $topicreplycount ; ?></b><br>Replies</p></div>
    <div class="topiclistlastposted"><?php if(!empty($topicreplyuser)){ ?><p>By: <b><?php echo $topicreplyuser ; ?></b> On<br><?php echo $betterTime->dateAndtime($topicreplydate); ?></p><?php } else { ?><p>By: <b><?php echo $topicusername ; ?></b> On<br><?php echo $betterTime->dateAndtime($topicreplydate); ?></p><?php } ?></div>
</li>
<?php } } else { ?>
<li><p class="morepadding">No Topics Regarding Your Search Words :(</p></li>
<?php } ?>
```

Here is the database input on the pagination class:

```
$freebiesquery = $pdo->prepare($string . " LIMIT " . $maxlimit);
$freebiesquery->execute($prep);
$freebiesquery_num = $freebiesquery->rowCount();
```

All this works on other pages so it has to be the way Im doing the header section of the code, the way im formating the sql query in the first place.

The only errors I am getting are as follows:

Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number

And

Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number

But this cant be as I have counted thema and they are the same?

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is a so-called "too localized" question, means you're asking for help not with some general purpose problem but merely to debug your own particular code - so, it won't help anyone else. Though I'd take a look if I get time, you'd better debug it yourself a bit, to narrow a problem to some certain point.

Comment: This infact may help someone else, because its asking about the sql injection, how to insert a sql database the correct way. Its not the coding which is giving off a bad response it seems to be the execution of the sql statement

Comment: Watch out for the precedence of `AND` versus `OR` in SQL expressions, you might need to add some parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting strings containing `=>` into an array doesn't make associations. `=>` is part of the syntax of array literals, they have to be outside the strings.

Replace:

```
$prep[] = "':productid{$i}' => {$productid}";
```

with:

```
$prep[":productid{$i}"] = $productid};
```

Replace:

```
$e = "':productid' =>" .  $_SESSION["SESS_USERSPRODUCTIDS"];
```

With:

```
$prep = array(':productid' => $_SESSION["SESS_USERSPRODUCTIDS"]);
```

Replace:

```
$prep       = array($e, ':like' => "%$searchword%", ':like2' => "%$searchword%");
```

with:

```
$prep[':like'] = "%$searchword%";
$prep[':like2'] = "%$searchword%";
```

Comment: this did the errors good :) but its not finsing any results which leads me to think its the way im asking for the data in the database.

Comment: Did you see my comment about parenthese?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, had to pick kids up from school... Yes I saw the comment and ive tried to using the () where possible with no joy :(

Comment: @Barmer I think I have done it and its thanks to you. Lesson to all, using parentheses when using multipul uses :)